# Generate hashtags from string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string from an input named 'text' and from this one, I would like to generate hashtags for a different field in my mongoose model:

```js
req.body.tags = req.body.text
  .split('#')
  .map((tag) =>
    tag.trim().replace(/ +/g, ' ').split(' ').join('-').toLowerCase()
  )
  .filter((tag) => tag.length !== 0)
```

The code above is almost perfect but every time, I press a comma it gets inserted as a hashtag(or part of it) which is something I'm trying to avoid as well, take a look into what I'm talking about:

```json
{
    "text": "Hola, mi nombre es Kevin y tu como te llamas? #random, #userundefined"
}
```

The text above is the data I insert via Postman and this is the output:

```json
"tags": [
  "hola,-mi-nombre-es-kevin-y-tu-como-te-llamas?",
  "random,",
  "userundefined"
],
```

What I would like to get is this:

```json
"tags": [
  "random",
  "userundefined"
],
```

I just want to retrieve the words followed by a `#` and just that, I don't want the **commas** after it as shown in the `random` tag

Comment: would a `?` be apart of the the text allowed in tags?

Comment: `.text.match(/(#\w+)/g)` ?

Comment: no unless it is located inside the word itself, example `#rand?om`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could play around with `req.body.text` in a slightly different way, now that I see you want to `filter out the tags` from full texts

**working example**

```js
//you can declare this function outside of whatever web-server callback you have
function tagsFrom(text){ //function
  var toReturn=[], i=0, hashtag=false
  let isNumber=(n)=>Number(n).toString()==n //!isNaN(n) doesn't work properly
  let isValidChar=(c)=>c=="_"?true:isNumber(c)||(c.toUpperCase()!=c.toLowerCase())
  for(let c of text){
    if(typeof toReturn[i]!="string"){toReturn[i]=""} //because I can't add a character to undefined
    if(c=="#"){hashtag=true;continue} //hashtag found
    if(isValidChar(c)&&hashtag){toReturn[i]+=c} //character of a hashtag word
    else if(hashtag){hashtag=false;i++} //no longer the hashtag
  }
  return toReturn.filter(tag=>tag.length&&!isNumber(tag))
  //no empty values and a tag can't be ONLY a number
}

var req={body:{text:"Hola, mi nombre es Kevin y tu como te llamas? #random, #userundefined #1 #spanish101 #, #1name ##underscore_test"}} //test variable
req.body.tags = tagsFrom(req.body.text) //usage
console.log(req.body.tags)
```

**MY EDIT**: I parse hashtags based on [this article about hashtags](https://www.hashtags.org/featured/what-characters-can-a-hashtag-include/)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. The only modification I added to your solution was on the return statement, `return toReturn.filter((tag) => tag.length !== 0)`. Your function kept returning empty hashtags but out of that, the solution makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: oof, empty tags.. didn't think about that one but yea, fun question

Answer (score 1):

[matchAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) should be usefull here...

The demo below is based on the documentation example. It returns an array of match arrays. In your case, you want the match[1] of each match, therefore the chained `map`.

```js
let text = "Hola, mi nombre es Kevin y tu como te llamas? #random, #userundefined, #user-defined, #Grand_Father, #test123Four, #99startWithNumberIsWrong, #911, #Special!characters?"

let validHashtags = [...text
  .toLowerCase()
  .matchAll(/#(([a-z_]+)([\w_]+)?)/g)]
  .map(match => match[1])
  
console.log(validHashtags)
```

So that would be:

```
req.body.tags = [...req.body.text
  .toLowerCase()
  .matchAll(/#(([a-z_]+)([\w_]+)?)/g)]
  .map(match => match[1])
```

I used a regular expression that complies with [hashtag.org](https://www.hashtags.org/featured/what-characters-can-a-hashtag-include/):

- No spaces
- No Special Characters
- Don't Start With or Use Only Numbers

For the length and slangs, you simply should advise your users about it when they enter the text.

Comment: You code was almost there but it was also removing the `-` characters!. Lol!.

Comment: I did not get the thing about `-`... You were replacing spaces by `-` (with split/join), but there is no practical use to it. No one will attempt to write a hashtag with a space. Except my Grand Pa, maybe.

Comment: no, as in the input being like `#some-tag` you would have `#some` as a key saved.. try this text for example `"Hola, mi nombre es Kevin y tu como te llamas? #random, #user-undefined"`

Comment: @TheBombSquad: lol I see... Edited. Added hypen and underscore.

Comment: Lol, yours is now working as I mainly wanted xD. This was a good question, lol. Thank you all, love you all, lol.

Comment: Also added digits and characters like `!` and `?` (while unsure about hashtag "standards")... That just depends on the regex you are using. Easy to adjust.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I looked up hashtag "standards" and apparently it's the `_` that's allowed not `-` and also numbers but not ONLY numbers.. I'm going to edit my question to suit.. see [here](https://www.hashtags.org/featured/what-characters-can-a-hashtag-include/)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to trim the commas off the ends of your tags after you split:

```
.map((tag) => {
  let newTag = tag.trim().replace(/ +/g, ' ').split(' ').join('-').toLowerCase();
  if (newTag.endsWith(',')) {
    newTag = newTag.substring(0, newTag.length - 1);
  }
  return newTag;
})
```

EDIT: If you're trying to get rid of anything that *isn't* preceded by a hashtag, you need to do your split a little differently. I would recommend maybe looking for `.indexOf('#')` and using `.substring()` to remove anything up to that index, then do your split.

Comment: Well, so far I've been able to remove the last comma from the strings.

Comment: isn't that what you want?

Comment: Yes and no. Right now the only problem left would be sentences not including the `#` character. As of now, the code above with your addition, keeps adding the text of `hola,-mi-nombre-es-kevin-y-tu-como-te-llamas?` which is something I also want to get rid off.

Comment: @Kirasiris I have the answer that does specifically what you want

Comment: @Kirasiris see my edit

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to match digits only, or start with a digit you can use a capture group and use for example matchAll to get the group value.

```
\B#([^\W\d]\w*)\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `\B#` A non word boundary followed by matching #
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\W\d]\w*` Match a word character not being a digit, then match optional word characters
- `)` Close group 1
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6EDVJA/1)

Example code:

```js
const s = "Hola, mi nombre es Kevin y tu como te llamas? #random, #userundefined";
const regex = /\B#([^\W\d]\w*)\b/g;
console.log(Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => m[1]));
```